# Libre office will not open

Tags: libreoffice

have ubuntu 14.04 LTS have used libre office for a while just stopped opening one day. gives an error message stating has experienced an internal error. Have tried uninstalling libre office and reinstalling. Have downloaded direct from libre office and reinstalled still no luck.

Comment: What if you run it from the terminal (just type libreoffice and hit enter)? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: tried from terminal, didn't open. banner came up but nothing else happened.

Comment: tried uninstalling it via `apt-get purge libreoffice` to remove config files too? If that will still work with the non-Ubuntu version you downloaded & presumably installed

Comment: yes, totally removed that way and installed open office, but I didn't like it so i tried reinstalling and same thing happened.

Comment: Daniel, there is a hidden folder `~/.config` (so in your home directory). Could you make it visible by typing Ctrl+H while in your home directory and remove the libreoffice folder inside that folder? Good chance that all works fine then. Possibly (probably, my guess) some settings file is damaged. Those files are not removed when uninstalling I believe.

Comment: Hi Daniel, does it work? let me know :) If so, we could convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Daniel, there is a hidden folder ~/.config (so in your home directory). Could you make >it visible by typing Ctrl+H while in your home directory and remove the libreoffice >folder inside that folder? Good chance that all works fine then. Possibly (probably, my >guess) some settings file is damaged. Those files are not removed when uninstalling I >believe. –  Jacob Vlijm 2 days ago"

After removing the libreoffice folder, I restarted the computer, reinstalled libreoffice and it ran fine.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site. I didn't want to leave the question unanswered.

Comment: No problem, maybe I should have answered earlier, I was pretty sure that this was it.