# Libreoffice calc is minimized

Tags: libreoffice

Whenever I click on Libreoffice calc it launches, but the window is minimized (I am not able to view it when I hover the icon with my mouse). All the other Libreoffice software works.

```
/etc/libreoffice$ ls
psprint.conf  registry  sofficerc  soffice.sh
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LibreOfficeCalc window is shrunk to a line and is unclickable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275213/libreofficecalc-window-is-shrunk-to-a-line-and-is-unclickable)

Comment: Used this and it [worked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643382/libre-office-wont-open) when I tried it again (I probably didn't log out for it to work). If it happens again I'll try your answer!

Comment: It's usually the case that after you have sized the screen to your requirement, it remembers the setting for subsequent use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Libre Office won't open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643382/libre-office-wont-open)